# What does 'repacking' mean?

Tags: meaning

I could only guess its meaning from the context. What does it exactly mean?

> In the 17th century, the philosopher Benedict de Spinoza engaged in
>   his own mid-life **repacking**. He began by considering the efforts
>   involved in pursuing what most people esteemed as the highest good ―
>   riches, fame, and the pleasure of the senses. Spinoza concluded that,
>   while these had their attractions, they could never provide him with
>   the authentic happiness for which he was searching. He made a great
>   discovery, which he phrased as follows: “Happiness or unhappiness is
>   made wholly to depend on the quantity of the object which we love.” If
>   we love transient attractions and values, our happiness will be
>   fleeting and transitory as well. On the other hand, if we seek to fix
>   our love to longer-lasting values, our happiness likewise tends to
>   persevere.

Comment: You should at least tell us your guess. Questions that simply ask "What does this mean?" that (a) have no indication of where the quote came from, and (b) do not show/share any research (such as a dictionary definition or Google search) are subject to closure.

Comment: OK, I got it. I'll keep that in mind. Thank you, J.R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This quote is from a book titled: *[Repacking Your Bags: Lighten Your Load for the Rest of Your Life](https://books.google.co.th/books?id=sh4ETPJ94ZQC&pg=PA262&lpg=PA262&dq=In%20the%2017th%20century,%20the%20philosopher%20Benedict%20de%20Spinoza%20engaged%20in%20his%20own%20mid-life%20repacking.%20He%20began%20by%20considering%20the%20efforts%20involved%20in%20pursuing%20what%20most%20people%20esteemed%20as%20the%20highest%20good%20%E2%80%95%20riches,%20fame,%20and%20the%20pleasure%20of%20the%20senses.%20Spinoza%20concluded%20that,%20while%20these%20had%20their%20attractions,%20they%20could%20never%20provide%20him%20with%20the%20authentic%20happiness%20for%20which%20he%20was%20se&source=bl&ots=tiv9wv8nar&sig=KmTRmz0iZzMxbLSwrjis15UFaOQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjmk82h5Y7bAhUGQ48KHX53AjQQ6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=repacking&f=false)*

On page xix of this book:

> *Repacking* uses the metaphor of travel—and baggage—to help remind you that life is a journey and that your experience on the way is inextricably bound up in the baggage—emotional, intellectual, and physical—that you are carrying.

And here is the paragraph just before the one you ask about:

> Life is nothing else than a dynamic process. It's impossible to somehow find and catch happiness, because as soon as you trap it, it begins to wither. That's actually what repacking is all about--it's a system for helping you with the continuing search. No matter what form that system takes, it has to come from within.
>
> In the 17th century, ....

So this book explains about life using a metaphor where: travel = life; 
baggage = feelings, thoughts, and possessions

**Therefore, repacking is also a metaphor for the system of rearranging our feelings, thoughts, and possessions in a better way to live a better life.**